# How to validate textfield with 0 to 59, it will allow 1,2,3,*/59

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need to validate Textbox for this test cases.

1. It will allow 0 to 59 no characters and special character not allowed except *,/
2. It will allow 1,2,3,4 but 1,2,3,60 should not allow
3. It will allow */59 or 1,2,3,4,*/59 but 1,2,3,5,*/59/19 should not allow

i tried,

```
var input = document.getElementById('configMinute').value;      

            //console.info("Else Called");
                var slashPattern = "/"; 
                var specialChars = "<>@!#$%^&*()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\,./~`-=";
                var getStringCheck = checkSpecialChar(input,specialChars);

                if(getStringCheck==true){   

                // string = 1,2,3,*/10
                // ,*/

                    var getStringValues = input.split(',');     

                    var notAllowedCharPattern = "<>@!#$%^&()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\.~`-=";

                    var allowedChar = checkSpecialChar(input,notAllowedCharPattern);

                        if(allowedChar==false){ 
                        console.info(getStringValues);

                            getStringValues.forEach(function(element){  
                            //string = 1 2 3 */10
                                var validateSlash = checkSpecialChar(element,slashPattern);     

                                if(element.startsWith("*")==true){
                                    var newInput = element.split('/');  
                                    console.info("newInput: "+ element);
                                    newInput.forEach(function(element) {
                                        console.info("newInput Foreach: "+ element);
                                        if(element=='*' || (element>=0 && element <=59)){   
                                            return true;                    
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            alert("Please enter numbers between 0 to 59 or '*' ==>1");
                                            document.getElementById('configMinute').focus();
                                            return false;

                                        }
                                    });                         

                                }else{
                                    console.info("* Else: "+ element);
                                    if(element=='*' || (element>=0 && element <=59)){   
                                        return true;                    
                                    }else{
                                        alert("Please enter numbers between 0 to 59 or '*' ==>1");
                                        document.getElementById('configMinute').focus();
                                        return false;

                                    }
                                }               

                            }); 
                        }else{
                            alert ("File name has special characters \nAllowed Characters are *,/ ==>3");
                            document.getElementById('configMinute').focus();
                            return false;
                        }           
                }else if(input == '*' || (input>=0 && input <=59)){ 
                    return true;        
                }else{
                    alert("Please enter numbers between 0 to 59 or '*' ==>4");
                    document.getElementById('configMinute').focus();
                    return false;
                }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried *anything*?

Comment: I validate first 2 cases, 3rd one i cant able

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regex like

```
(?:(?:^|,)(?:[1-5]?\d|\*?\/59)\b)+$
```

It matches the beginning of the line (`^`) or a `,` followed by either a number, 0-59, or `/59` optionally preceded by a `*`. And this pattern can then repeat any number of times, until the end of the line.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/D7y8hH/2).

Comment: it has issues not working properly, test cases: 1)59 2)1,2 3)1,2,*/59 4)*/59 5) *

Comment: Well, as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/D7y8hH/4), it **does** work with the first four. The fifth is however not mentioned in the question, and therefore doesn't work ;)

Comment: hi mentioned but you not understand, or i am not said clearly. anyway can you help me to complete

Comment: I need to validate this 5,*,1,2,3,*/5, Either combined or alone each character